# Windows2012+php+mysql+apache - замирает жесткий диск

Tags: php, mysql

Привет,
есть работающий проект документооборота на PHP. Машина на которую поставлен -
 Windows2012+php+mysql+apache виртуальная с 2 процессорами 4 ГБ и жесткий диск 7200об/мин.

ДО 120 пользователей работает пулей, но после 130 где-то иногда происходит странная штука - диск на 10-40 секунд просто замирает. На мониторе активности диска показывается Высокая 100% активность (Синяя полоска на графике, хотя чтение-запись не происходит - это зеленый график), хотя процессор занят на  16% всего.

Были разные предположения - дедлоки, нехватка оперативки, антивирус windows-protect... но пока так и не разобрался что это. При этом удаленный рабочий стол работает нормально, не тупит.

В момент тормазов - свободной оперативной памяти видел либо 0 либо очень мало.

Есть предположения?

Comment: Свопит из-за нехватки памяти?

Comment: Да, спс сегодня тоже об этом подумал, но еще не успел дополнительной оперативной памяти попросить для теста.

Comment: Версия со свопом не подтвердилась - только что была задержка на 15 сек, и было 300МБ свободных.

Comment: 300 свободных еще ничего не означает. Посмотрите колонку Page Fault Delta (PF Delta) в Task Manager - так должны быть сильно ненулевые значения при свопе. Ну и вообще посмотрите значения в perf mon для диска - хотя бы длину очереди.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ура, ответ найден - причина в настройке mysql-сервера innodb_io_capacity
Для моего медленного диска это 100. А по умолчанию эта настройка стоит 200.
Удивительно просто что это оказало такое фатальное влияние.
Всем огромное спасибо.

Comment: Опс, оказалось что это не окончательная правда. Итог - истинная причина - это взаимные блокировки))... а настрока innodb_io_capacity еще больше ухудшала ситуацию.

Comment: Пришлось использовать неблокирующее чтение (select внутри транзакции) и кеширование в большем объеме на стороне PHP. И это сейчас позволяет держать 150 постоянных пользователей вполне.